# how to avoid commerce price to be rounded

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to add an optional insurance field to my order total amount.

For that I use a fee which is calculated and added to this amount.

Everything is ok except that when I continue to checkout, this amount is rounded to the superior .5

For example I have a total amount of 282.00€, I add 1% for insurance, fee is calculated as 2.82€ and when I arrive to checkout, it's rounded to 2.85€...

I don't want this amount to be rounded, in Euro you can have cents, so 1% is 1%, not 1.x %...

Is it possible to disable this rounding operation ?

Thanks in advance for your answers